# What are Parameters in Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, intuition

I'm totally lost about what parameters are in Set Theory. I've been looking through a bunch of books but none explicitly state what they are, only how they are used in formulas to make sets. Can someone please explain this idea?

Comment: Can you give an example of a phrase or statement that uses the term in the way that confuses you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "parameter" (in what I assume is the context you have in mind) is just a specific set that is plugged in for a variable in a formula.  For instance, the axiom schema of separation says that if $A$ and $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ are sets and $\varphi(x,y_1,\dots,y_n)$ is a formula in the language of set theory (whose free variables are $x,y_1,\dots,y_n$), then there exists a set $B$ such that for all $z$, $$z\in B \leftrightarrow(z\in A\wedge\varphi(z,Y_1,\dots,Y_n)).$$ In this context, we refer to the sets $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ as "parameters" which are being used in the formula $\varphi$ to define the set $Z$.

Comment: So if I wanted to make a formula that says x is the set of even integers, I could use a set that defines the integers as a parameter in my formula?

Comment: Sure.  The point is that individual specific sets are not themselves part of the language of set theory (only general variables that represent sets), so when you plug in a specific set for a variable (a "parameter") you are giving yourself some extra expressive power.

Comment: You mean the integers, for example, aren't a specific set in the language of set theory, but I can define a set in the language of set theory that has the properties of the integers which I can use in formulas as a parameter when I want to say things like "x is the set of all even integers"?

Comment: Not quite.  If you define a set that is the integers entirely in the language of set theory (which is possible), then you don't need to use it as a parameter at all, since you can just insert that definition.  But there are (or at least it is possible that there are) sets which you can't define at all in the language of set theory, and you are still nevertheless allowed to use those sets as parameters in defining other sets.

Comment: I'm also not entirely sure that I'm thinking about the same context as you are, so if you want a more definite answer you should provide more context.

Comment: I was under the impression that a parameter was just a set definable in the language of set theory. Are you saying that a parameter is something that is outside the language altogether? To give more context, I am thinking about parameters as they are mentioned in the axioms of comprehension and replacement.

Comment: In the axioms of comprehension and replacement, the "parameters" are nothing more than certain variables appearing in the axioms, for which you can substitute any specific sets (since those variables are universally quantified).  The point of including these parameters is that they allow your definitions of sets via these axioms to refer to arbitrary other sets (the $Y_i$ in my answer), not merely other sets which are definable in the language of set theory.

Comment: For instance, using the axiom of comprehension, you can prove that $X\cap Y$ is a set for any sets $X$ and $Y$, by defining the set $\{x\in X:x\in Y\}$ (where $Y$ is a _parameter_).  If you weren't allowed to use parameters (that is, the formula $\varphi$ in my answer could not have any free variables besides $x$), you would not be able to define a set in this way unless you could express "$x\in Y$" purely in the language of set theory, without referring to $Y$ itself or any other fixed individual sets.  You can't necessarily do this for an arbitrary set $Y$.

Comment: So to summarize, a parameter is just a set that can be used in formulas that may not be expressible in the language of set theory. Hence, they add expressive power to the language. (Thanks for taking the time to explain this.)

Comment: I have one question how exactly would you express $Y_{1},Y_{2},Y_{3}…,Y{n}$ are sets? If you’d want to make this fully formal you’d have to add universal quantifies at the start, correct?

Comment: @VioletFlame: In the context of ZFC, there are no objects other than sets, so there is no need to express that.  So you would just say $\forall Y_1\forall Y_2\dots$.

Comment: I suppose we need parameters due to the existence of undefinable sets? It was explained to me that undefinable sets exist because there are uncountable amount of sets but a countable amount of formulas but that doesn’t make any sense to me how does the meta theory prove there are an uncountable amount of sets?

Comment: @VioletFlame: There are models in which every set is definable but there are also models in which not every set is definable.  In any case, the point of parameters is to allow you to refer to specific sets without needing to know a definition of them.  This is extremely useful.

Comment: For instance, say you want to prove that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $\{y\in\mathbb{R}:y<x\}$ is a set.  This is trivial using Separation if you can use $x$ as a parameter.  Without parameters, you can only prove this for each individual $x$ that you can define, and it is a separate proof for each separate value of $x$.  In particular, without using $x$ as a parameter you can't (in any obvious way) prove the universally quantified statement that this is a set *for all* $x\in\mathbb{R}$.